# Volume on Docker Swarm is not persistent?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I just want to create a service on Docker Swarm with NGINX and to make data persistent after docker-machine reboot.

I check the manager IP

`docker-machine ip manager`

Then I go to the machine

`docker-machine ssh manager`

Inside a Docker Machine I create a new service:

`docker service create -p 80:80 --mount type=volume,target=/usr/share/nginx/html --name nginx nginx`

Here I expect to have a service running with NGINX on the port 80 with an unnamed volume.

In a web browser I see that NGINX is online at MANAGER_IP:80.

With `docker inspect CONTAINER_ID` can find the path to the volume and to modify e.g. `index.html`.

But after `docker-machine stop` and `docker-machine start` my change disappears.

Why? What do I have to do to make it persistent (to be available after rebooting docker-machine) ?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this

`docker service create -p 80:80 --mount type=volume,source=myvolume,destination=/usr/share/nginx/html --name nginx nginx`

You just didn't mention the source in your command